# SED replace each placeholder with variable lines in file

Tags: file, variables, text, sed, replace

```
sed -e "s/Var4/r {replace.txt} /g" "input.txt" > "output.txt"
```

Var4:
placeholder to be replaced

replace.txt
contains variable data

input.txt:
input file

output.txt
output file

each occurrence of  "Var4"  in  "input.txt"  should be replaced by a variable line in  "replace.txt", but sed reads  "replace.txt"  as normal text not a file name:

Incorrect: 
    TextBox1.Value = "r replace.txt"

Correct: 
    TextBox1.Value = "0000AAAA"

I tired searching all similar posts for the correct syntax but no use !

Thank You

Input.txt

```
TextBox1.Value = "Var4"
Else
TextBox1.Value = "- - - - - - -"
End If

TextBox1.Value = "Var4"
Else
TextBox1.Value = "- - - - - - -"
End If
```

Output.txt should look like this:

```
TextBox1.Value = "0000AAAA"
Else
TextBox1.Value = "- - - - - - -"
End If

TextBox1.Value = "0000BBBB"
Else
TextBox1.Value = "- - - - - - -"
End If
```

Replace.txt

```
0000AAAA
0000BBBB
0000CCCC
```

I also tried

```
sed -e "s/Var4/$(<replace.txt sed -e 's/[\&/]/\\&/g' -e 's/$/\\n/' | tr -d '\n')/g" "input.txt" > "output.txt"
```

but the output is still incorrect:

```
TextBox1.Value = "0000AAAA
0000BBBB
0000CCCC
"
Else
TextBox1.Value = "- - - - - - -"
End If

TextBox1.Value = "0000AAAA
0000BBBB
0000CCCC
"
Else
TextBox1.Value = "- - - - - - -"
End If
```

Update 1:

```
sed '/Var4/R replace.txt' input.txt | sed '/Var4/{N;s/"Var4"\n\(.*\)/"\1"/}' > "output.txt"
```

Works perfectly if "Var4" is at the end of the line, however if any text exists after it, the output is incorrect ?

Input.txt

```
TextBox1.Value = "Var4"  Then
Else
TextBox1.Value = "- - - - - - -"
End If

TextBox1.Value = "Var4"  Then
Else
TextBox1.Value = "- - - - - - -"
End If
```

Output.txt should look like this:

```
TextBox1.Value = "0000AAAA"  Then
Else
TextBox1.Value = "- - - - - - -"
End If

TextBox1.Value = "0000BBBB"  Then
Else
TextBox1.Value = "- - - - - - -"
End If
```

Replace.txt

```
0000AAAA
0000BBBB
0000CCCC
```

Output.txt after using:

```
sed '/Var4/R replace.txt' input.txt | sed '/Var4/{N;s/"Var4"\n\(.*\)/"\1"/}' > "output.txt"

TextBox1.Value = "Var4"  Then
0000AAAA
Else
TextBox1.Value = "- - - - - - -"
End If

TextBox1.Value = "Var4"  Then
0000BBBB
Else
TextBox1.Value = "- - - - - - -"
End If
```

Any Advice ?

Comment: Windows does not natively include `sed` except for the WSL option in Windows 10, so you must have got it from another source; most such sources also provide or offer `awk` and/or `perl` either of which would be much better suited for this problem.

Comment: I installed bash on windows for consistency, and it works, it's just a matter of getting right syntax to achieve the right result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/Var4/R replaceFile' file | sed '/Var4/{N;s/"Var4"\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/"\2"\1/}'
```

Append the replacement line after the place holder then in a separate sed invocation, append the line following the place holder and use the substitution command to effect the desired result.

N.B. The `R` command only reads the following file a line at a time, unlike the `r` command which reads the entire file each time it is called.

Comment: Well done! I just changed the input and output file names to match the original post.

Comment: sed '/Var4/R replace.txt' input.txt | sed '/Var4/{N;s/"Var4"\n\(.*\)/"\1"/}' > "output.txt"   works BUT, "Var4" must be at the end of the line ! what if there is text after it ?

Comment: @ potong Perfect :-)

Answer (score 0):

`sed`'s `r` command can only output the content of the file to stdout. You can not get that content in the pattern space, neither can you inject that content in another `sed` command (like the one in your question).

Just use the shell to achieve that. Here is a solution with a Bourne shell since I don't know Windows:

```
sed -e "s/Var4/$(cat replace.txt)/g" "input.txt" > "output.txt"
```

Here I'm assuming the content of `replace.txt` is similar to your example (0000AAAA) and does not contain any "/", otherwise choose another separator than "/" in your `s///` command.

Comment: 1. under windows cmd > output still incorrect TextBox1.Value = "r replace.txt"

2. under bash > error > unterminated 's' command

Comment: 1. No surprise, I didn't provide any enhancement to your Windows command. 2. Your file `replace.txt` probably contains more than one line. It should contain one single line with 0000AAAA (or any other data, as long as there are no "/" inside). If you want to insert line skips in output.txt, separate lines with `\n`, like that: `0000AAAA\n0000BBBB\n0000CCCC`

Comment: If you want to insert the whole content of `replace.txt` at places marked with `Var4`, see my previous comment. If you want to insert one precise line among those 3000 lines, then I didn't understand your problem: explain in your question how that line is supposed to be chosen and give a small carefully-chosen sample of both `replace.txt` and `input.txt`.

Comment: I installed bash on windows for consistency, and it works, it's just a matter of getting right syntax to achieve the right result. Please see examples I posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/Var4/R replace.txt' input.txt | sed '/Var4/{N;s/"Var4"\n\(.*\)/"\1"/}' > "output.txt"
```

Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/967492/potong > this works on GNU bash !

Comment: If you want to thank potong, just add a comment to their answer and click the up arrow beside it.